# Why do modules run multiple times on a single page load?

Tags: hooks

In Drupal 7 created a module which implemented `hook_init()`.

I put an error log message as the first line of the function.

```
function my_module_init() {
  error_log('running init');
}
```

On each page load of the site I see the error message multiple times. I was expecting `hook_init()` to be ran exactly once per page load. Why is it running multiple times?

Comment: A similar issue was discussed in [Alternatives to hook_init()](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36265/alternatives-to-hook-init). The comments and the accepted answer are highly recommended.

Comment: In the other question, the fact `hook_init()` is invoked twice is just marginal. The main question is about alternatives to `hook_init()`, as the title says. In fact, the accepted answer offers an alternative implementation of `hook_init()`, alternative hooks to implement, and an explanation of why `hook_init()` is not invoked twice per page request; the latter part is marginal for that question, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hook_init()` is invoked by Drupal only once for each requested page; it is the last step done in [_drupal_bootstrap_full()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

```
  // Drupal 6
  //
  // Let all modules take action before menu system handles the request
  // We do not want this while running update.php.
  if (!defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE') || MAINTENANCE_MODE != 'update') {
    module_invoke_all('init');
  }
```

```
  // Drupal 7
  //
  // Let all modules take action before the menu system handles the request.
  // We do not want this while running update.php.
  if (!defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE') || MAINTENANCE_MODE != 'update') {
    // Prior to invoking hook_init(), initialize the theme (potentially a custom
    // one for this page), so that:
    // - Modules with hook_init() implementations that call theme() or
//   theme_get_registry() don't initialize the incorrect theme.
    // - The theme can have hook_*_alter() implementations affect page building
//   (e.g., hook_form_alter(), hook_node_view_alter(), hook_page_alter()),
//   ahead of when rendering starts.
    menu_set_custom_theme();
    drupal_theme_initialize();
    module_invoke_all('init');
  }
```

If `hook_init()` is being executed more than once per each page request, there could be a module that calls [module_invoke_all('init')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7). It could also happens that a module calls [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7), and redirects the user to another page; this would cause a new page request, and a new invocation of `hook_init()`, if the page is not served from the cache.

In Drupal 7, there is just a way to check if `hook_init()` is invoked twice per page request, and it is to implement `hook_init()` using the following code.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  watchdog('mymodule', 'Request time: !timestamp', array('!timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
}
```

As [REQUEST_TIME](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/REQUEST_TIME/7) is a constant that Drupal defines each times it bootstraps (which means each times a page is requested), if you see two consecutive `watchdog()` entries showing the same value, then `hook_init()` is being invoked twice, or it is invoked in two different page requests done in less than a second. If the difference is 2 seconds, for example, then `hook_init()` is invoked in two different page requests.

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) runs once per page request on all non-cached pages.

Keep in mind that when you load a page in your browser, it loads the page and all assets on that page (CSS, JS, images, etc).

Also keep in mind that Drupal handles 404 errors by default<sup>1</sup>, so if there is a bad URL on the page (say /favicon.ico), then Drupal may handle that asset, depending on how you have Apache configured.

Image styles used on a page that don't have derivatives on the filesystem will also get handled by Drupal and go through the whole bootstrap process.

My advice is to try to match up the timestamps in the error log with the Apache access_log and see what is going on.

So, it is very likely that your multiple entries in the error log from `hook_init()` are from individual URLs that Drupal has handled in quick succession, but potentially from starting from a single browser page load.

<sup>1</sup> This bahavior can be refined in more recent versions of Drupal 7.

Comment: You mentioned loading images.  Would requesting images trigger hook_init()? I don't see why requesting an image would be considered as a page request.

Comment: If they are defined as image styles, then the first load may trigger Drupal to render out the derivative.