# dpm() in hook_init shows twice on the page

Tags: 7, hooks

In my custom module, I use a `hook_init()` with a `dpm`-function.

```
function mymodule_init() {
    dpm('check');
}
```

but for some reason, my page shows 2 times 'check' on the page... Is this default Drupal behavior? And if so, what are the reason for this behavior?

Comment: it should appear only once, cleared cache?
Try this way and see what happends?
drupal_set_message("check",'ok', false);

Comment: Ofcourse with the `false` parameter, the message shows only once. But I would like to know why the message is showing twice even though it only should appear once in `hook_init()`

Comment: This answer from this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36265/alternatives-to-hook-init should be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

[hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) runs once per-page request, for non-cached pages.

See [_drupal_bootstrap_full](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_full/7)

```
module_invoke_all('init');
```

I guess what's perhaps happening in your case is an additional ajax request is bootstrapping Drupal and triggering an additional `hook_init` call.

Comment: I believe this is often the case with [admin menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu).

Comment: Could also be a 404 from a linked asset on the page.